# how to pass value to popup window using php loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to pass product id to popup window in the same page.how to pass id to popup window?this is my code:

Display all products from table:

```
<?php $data = mysql_query("select * from tbl_product") ;
    while($dat=mysql_fetch_array($data))
    {
        $id=$dat['id']

       ?>
       <a href="<?php echo $id ?> " class="mymodel" data-detail-id=<?php echo $id ?> data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">  
       <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12"  style="cursor:pointer;">
       <div class="col-md-12" >

       <img src="../admin/product_image/<?php echo $dat['image'] ?>" >

       <h4><?php echo $dat['name'] ?></h4>
       </div></div></a>
       <?php  } ?>
```

javascript:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $('#myInput').focus()
   })</script>
```

Popup Window code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"       aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">    
 <?php
 $data = mysql_query("select * from tbl_product where id='$id'") ;
    while($dat=mysql_fetch_array($data))
    {
        $id=$dat['id'] ;
    } 
    ?>
   <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
   <?php echo $id ?>
   </div>
   </div></div>
```

Comment: You should look into using mysqli or PDO to connect to your database for security reasons.

Comment: its not database error, how can i pass value to popup?

Comment: Hello creative, you need to understand first that although you can pass the value the modal you are calling is on the same page and as such your php code will not get executed, instead it will just get executed once when the page is loaded and that is that. You should try calling a different url via ajax and then showing the result via a popup.

Comment: Plz explain how to do this?or send me a sample code.